# huawei usb modem is not detected as I plug-in

Tags: usb-modem

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 on Lenovo g40-30 but my modem is not detected when I plug-in. I tried different ways without success.

Anyone please help me.

Comment: Which is the output of `lsusb` ?

Comment: `15.04` has reached end of life status. Please upgrade to a recent, supported version of Ubuntu. Otherwise this question is off-topic.